# Python - Replace i value instead of appending

Tags: python, matplotlib, append

I am trying to plot real time data. I managed to plot the data but I would like for the bar graph to go up and down on a single x-value rather than produce new x-values for every new datapoint. I believe I have to replace the function x.append(i) with something like a replace, any ideas? Thank you!!

So far this is what I came up with:

```
import time
import psutil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.show()
plt.axis('off')

i = 0
x, y = [], []

while True:
    x.append(i)
    y.append(psutil.cpu_percent())
    
    ax.bar(x, y, color='b')
    
    fig.canvas.draw()
    
    ax.set_xlim(left=max(0, i-50), right=i+50)
    
    time.sleep(0.1)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the bar graph you can create a list inside the while loop, and instantly update it there. First you need to import a random in order get random value for y axis, or you can use `cpu_percent`.

```
import psutil 
import random
```

These two should work.
And then:

```
while True: 
    x_axis = [str(_) for _ in range(100, 200)]
    y_axis = [8 * random.random() for _ in range(100, 200)]
    ax.bar(x, y, color='b')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

However, `matplotlib` is not convenient for real data plotting, I strongly recommend you to use `bokeh`. You can find bokeh documentation [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/index.html). It is really cool for creating any kind of real time plot. And at the same time, you can integrate it with your web browser. Hope this will help you)

Comment: Thank you! Very useful resources (:

Comment: Unfortunately, I receive the following error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_526/3961775249.py in <module>
      9     x_axis = [str(_) for _ in range(100, 200)]
     10     y_axis = [8 * random.random() for _ in range(100, 200)]
---> 11     ax.bar(x, y, color='b')
     12     fig.canvas.draw()
     13     time.sleep(0.1)

NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: Have you tried my second option, that should work. Bokeh is very comfortable for streaming data.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the latest value, you can consider doing something like:

```
plt.ion()
graph = plt.bar(["Now"], [0])[0]
plt.axis('off')

i = 0
data = {}

while True:

    cpu_percent = psutil.cpu_percent()
    
    graph.set_ydata(cpu_percent)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.1)

    data[i] = cpu_percent 
    i += 1
```

This way, you still have a record of all the datapoints to play with later (x, y) but you will only display 1 x value at a time on the graph.

[Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446443/live-updating-with-matplotlib)

Comment: Thank you! I do get the following error though: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_184/3640181601.py in <module>
     10     cpu_percent = psutil.cpu_percent()
     11 
---> 12     graph.set_ydata(cpu_percent)
     13     plt.draw()
     14     plt.pause(0.1)

AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no attribute 'set_ydata'

Comment: Can you try `graph.set_height(cpu_percent)` instead of `graph.set_ydata(cpu_percent)`?